# How to configure a Shadow Plugin fat jar to bundle and access web.xml and context.xml locations?

Tags: gradle, tomcat, fatjar, gradle-shadow-plugin

I have a `Tomcat Embedded` project that I want to run using a `fat jar` with [Shadow Plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)

My Gradle in `build.gradle.kts` configuration looks like this for the parts related to Shadow:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
}
...
tasks {
    "build" {
        dependsOn(shadowJar)
    }
    shadowJar {
        mergeServiceFiles()
        manifest.inheritFrom(jar.get().manifest) // This makes the shadowJar (produced by jar task) runnable..
        // This allows java to run the generated .jar file recognizing the Main class for this project.
        manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "some.project.package.Main"
        manifest.attributes["Implementation-Version"] = version

    }
}
```

My `Main.main` method for Tomcat embedded looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Application context path
        String contextPath = "/";
        String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";

        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(PORT);

        Context context = tomcat.addWebapp(
                contextPath, new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath()
        );

        // Define and bind web.xml file location.
        File configFile = new File(webappDirLocation + "WEB-INF/web.xml");
        context.setConfigFile(configFile.toURI().toURL());

        tomcat.start();
      
        System.out.println("Server");
        System.out.println("listening on");
        System.out.println("http://" + tomcat.getHost().getName() + ":" + tomcat.getConnector().getPort() + "/" );
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
```

`gradle build` now generates a `fat jar` in the `/build/libs` folder. However, when I run it using `java -jar project_name-version-all.jar`, it then tries to run `some.project.package.Main` and fails with this error:

```
SEVERE: Missing context.xml: [file:/home/user/repo/build/libs/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/repo/build/libs/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml (No such file or directory)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:631)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:849)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:400)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Sep 25, 2022 5:35:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processContextConfig
SEVERE: Parse error in context.xml for []
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/repo/build/libs/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml (No such file or directory)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:189)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:653)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:150)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:861)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1525)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:849)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:400)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Sep 25, 2022 5:35:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base [/home/user/repo/build/libs/src/main/webapp] does not exist or is not a readable directory
        at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5448)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Sep 25, 2022 5:35:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:804)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5449)
        ... 7 more

Sep 25, 2022 5:35:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:469)
        at some.project.package.Main.main(Main.java:29)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1238)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:804)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5449)
        ... 7 more

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1238)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:469)
        at some.project.package.Main.main(Main.java:29)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1238)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:804)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5449)
        ... 7 more
```

This error does not happen when I do `gradle run`. In that case the code runs normally.

From the error I can clearly see that it is looking for the file in my local machine's file system when it should be looking for it in the packaged `fat jar`.

When I opened the fat jar I couldn't find the webapp folder, neither could I find my project's `web.xml` or `context.xml` files.

Is there something I am missing to configure the Shadow plugin to export these locations into the `fat jar` and to load them properly on the `Main.main` method for `Tomcat embedded`?

Comment: any luck on this?